# Moral constructivism and intuitionistic logic

Tags: rawls, intuitionistic-logic

What with all the times Rawls uses mathematics examples in AToJ, such as the guy who counts blades of grass for fun and survives by solving math problems for a fee, or π being transcendental, or the property of being in the interior of the unit circle, etc. I wonder if his outside reference to moral construction was meant to imply that he thought moral logic was intuitionistic? This would make sense of the proceduralism and perspectivism involved, would it not?

Then again, he never says that the LEM isn't admissible in arguments for moral propositions...

Comment: Rawls models his constructivism on Kant's, so a connection to mathematical constructivism is certainly there. But one does not have to adopt first order intuitionistic logic to be a "constructivist" in meta-theory, in this case meta-ethics. Even if we accept LEM in the first order language Gödel's theorem still tells us that some sentences will remain undecidable. [Scanlon](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/1/17543101/1/Scanlon%20The%20Appeal%20and%20Limits.pdf) analogizes Rawls's position to pluralism about set theory, LEM is valid but some moral claims remain unresolved and up to choice.

Comment: this would make a more impressive question with more links to what you mean, because as it reads for now, well, i have no idea why Rawls would so covertly suggest that (that moral logic is intuitionistic). i don't even get the joke, moment

Comment: It wouldn't be covert so much as Rawls not realizing that less mathematically inclined readers would miss the tie-in. As it stands, constructivism in metaethics is not interpreted as a simple thesis about the kind of mathematical logic appropriate to moral discourse, but I wonder if it was "supposed" to be that simple? But he never mentions the LEM in this connection, afaik, so I wonder...

Comment: OK then maube i don't get what you mean @KristianBerry it's sounds fun and deconstructive, by you here, but i don't see it being overt, anymore than he is overtly saying that we have a moral obligation to count blades of grass and solve mathematical problems. does he use any less mathematical examples? anyway, that's not my point: which was that i can only just understand the question, having not read rawls' book. and in this instance, that is completely unnecessary!

Comment: I've read AToJ way too many times  but yeah, he even mentions Cantor at one point, he uses curves and summation notation over indices, talks about moral geometry, etc.

Comment: the last one is interesting. perhaps a figure of speech?

Comment: He means as rigorous a system as possible, so since he doesn't achieve the goal, he caveats his argument all the way through. Weirdly he seems in conflict with himself on this score later in the last section of the book when he appears to disavow a strict deductive method.